# problem with centering an element in hightcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I have a problem with hightcharts.

-I don't know how to make the element marked in the photo centered. I tried to read the documentation but nothing helped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5SAs.png)

-the second thing, I do not know how to manage the field (hight and width) contener (i.e. where there is a border)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r21C7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Obq4.png)

```html
        (function () {
                        var containerID = 'column-container';
                        var legendID = 'column-legend';
                        document.querySelector('#' + containerID).classList.add('ns-chart-column');
                        var cats = [
                            '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'
                        ];


                        var chart = Highcharts.chart(containerID, {

                            chart: {
                                type: 'column',
                                styledMode: true,
                                width: 500,
                                spacingRight: 100,
  
                            },

                            title: {
                                text: 'Reveneue',
                                align: 'left',
                                floating: true,
                                x: 80,
                                y: 40
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: 'kEUR',
                                align: 'left',
                                x: 80,
                                y: 60
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '',
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                useHTML: true,
                                shadow: false,
                                lineWidth: 400,
                                borderRadius: 0,
                                padding: 8
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: cats,
                                labels: {
                                    autoRotation: false,
                                    overflow: "allow",
                                    useHTML: true
                                },
                            },

                            series: [{
                                data: [{
                                    name: '452.84',
                                    y: 452.84,
                                    colorIndex: 1,
                                    pointWidth: 80,
                                }, {
                                    name: '684.54',
                                    y: 684.58,
                                    colorIndex: 2,
                                    pointWidth: 80,
                                }, {
                                    name: '953.43',
                                    y: 952.35,
                                    colorIndex: 3,
                                    pointWidth: 80,
                                }]
                            }]

                        });

                    })();
```

Comment: You can center your wrapper div adding this style `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: I tried css before, but it doesn't work: /

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x8a2r3vb/)